# Can't Use Double Quotations to use Variable inside Body for POST Request

Tags: powershell, api, invoke-restmethod

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'BLAHBLAHBLAH' -Method POST `
   -Headers $headers `
   -ContentType 'application/json' `
   -Body '{"archived":false,"warranty_months":null,
     "depreciate":false,
     "supplier_id":null,
     "requestable":false,
     "rtd_location_id":null,
     "last_audit_date":"null",
     "location_id":null,
     "status_id":2,
     "model_id":34,
     "serial":$SERIAL,
     "name":$COMPUTERNAME}'
```

For the body portion, i've used double and single quotes to no avail.  I've used the `"` " and ${SERIAL} and that hasn't helped either.  I can use single quotes to make the call but am not able to use my SERIAL variable.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hm. So i've tried that but when I use double quotes "" for expandable strings, I receive a positional parameter error but not for when I use singles quotes.  This is the body  section of the code.

Comment: Please see my answer; note that `"last_audit_date"` has a `null` as a _string_ value (`"null"`) - is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

- You must use `"..."` (double-quoting), i.e. an [*expandable string*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) in order to get *string interpolation* (expansion of variable values) in your string.

  - By contrast, `'...'` (single-quoting) is a [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), so any variable references such as `$SERIAL` in it are *not* expanded.
  - See the conceptual [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) help topic.
- Since you're trying to create a *JSON* string, any expanded variable values that represent *JSON strings* must be enclosed in *embedded* `"` characters, which you must escape as `` `" `` (or `""`), as *all* `"` chars. embedded inside `"..."` must be.

  - `` ` ``, the so-called *backtick*, is PowerShell's general escape character. Inside `"..."`, it not only escapes `"` and `$` to treat them literally, but also marks the start of *escape sequences* such as `` `n `` for an LF character - see [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters).

Therefore:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'BLAHBLAHBLAH' -Method POST `
   -Headers $headers `
   -ContentType 'application/json' `
   -Body "{`"archived`":false,`"warranty_months`":null,
     `"depreciate`":false,
     `"supplier_id`":null,
     `"requestable`":false,
     `"rtd_location_id`":null,
     `"last_audit_date`":`"null`",
     `"location_id`":null,
     `"status_id`":2,
     `"model_id`":34,
     `"serial`":`"$SERIAL`",
     `"name`":`"$COMPUTERNAME}`""
```

Note, however, that you can use a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) to avoid the need for escaping the embedded `"` chars:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'BLAHBLAHBLAH' -Method POST `
   -Headers $headers `
   -ContentType 'application/json' `
   -Body @"
{"archived":false,"warranty_months":null,
"depreciate":false,
"supplier_id":null,
"requestable":false,
"rtd_location_id":null,
"last_audit_date":"null",
"location_id":null,
"status_id":2,
"model_id":34,
"serial":"$SERIAL",
"name":"$COMPUTERNAME}"
"@
```

---

Finally, it may be easier to construct your data as a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) and let PowerShell convert it to JSON for you via [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json):

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'BLAHBLAHBLAH' -Method POST `
   -Headers $headers `
   -ContentType 'application/json' `
   -Body (
  @{
    archived = $false
    warranty_months = $null
    depreciate = $false
    supplier_id = $null
    requestable = $false
    rtd_location_id = $null
    last_audit_date = 'null'
    location_id = $null
    status_id = 2
    model_id = 34
    serial = $SERIAL
    name = $COMPUTERNAME
  } | ConvertTo-Json
)
```

Note how the hashtable keys don't need double-quoting (except if they contain special characters), and variables with string values can be used as-is (`ConvertTo-Json` automatically encloses them in `"..."`).

Comment: I see. Thank you. The hash-table was definitely worked and seems much more convenient to implement.

Comment: The last suggestion is definitely the best and most clean approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

agree with @mklement0, it is easier to use a hash table and convert to json later.
anyway it is possible to do it your way if you double the double quotes:

```
-Body "{
""archived"":""false"",
""warranty_months"":""null"",
""depreciate"":""false"",
""supplier_id"":""null"",
""requestable"":""false"",
""rtd_location_id"":""null"",
""last_audit_date"":""null"",
""location_id"":""null"",
""status_id"":2,
""model_id"":34,
""serial"":""$SERIAL"",
""name"":""$COMPUTERNAME""
}"
```

Comment: Glad to hear you agree. Inside `"..."`, you can embed `"` as either `\`"` _or_ `""` - makes no difference. Thus, your solution is in effect no different from the first one in my answer (I've updated my answer to note that `""` can be used too).